# Assertion failure: OpenCS with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera

I'm trying to use OpenCS to take a video with a webcam for further processing but keep getting `Failed if statement`

```
from cv2 import *

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

s, img = cam.read()

if s:
    nameWindow("cam-test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    ifshow('cam-test',img)
    waitKey(0)
    destroyWindow("cam-test")
     imwrite("filename.jpg", img)
else:
    print("Failed if statement")
```

Comment: Update: If someone could tell me why this doesn't open my image, that would be great too:

``import cv2

capture = cv2.imread("Capture.png")

cv2.imshow("Capture", capture)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()``

Comment: Do you have an extra camera? Normally, the default camera's index is 0 so if you want to capture from the default camera, you should declare `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Comment: and normally, we just use `import cv2`